# Captcha triggering in selenium web driver environment, worked then captcha then does not work at all

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, captcha

Hi I am working in the selenium webdriver environment, I am attempting to automate some web scraping. The extend of what I have done so far is below, all I have done so far is indentify the search bar then input a search. This was working fine but it seems that on a particular instance I had a captcha pop up. I solved it manually. However now when I run my program all that works is the navigation to the page. I am wondering a couple of things: Why does selenium webdriver trigger a captcha? I read that it has to do with the javascript of the site or the way that it was developed. Why is it that my program does nothing beyond just going to the site, not even triggering a captcha? Can it be that my user profile was recorded? Further is there a way to solve this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from parsel import Selector

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.zillow.com")
zillow_search=driver.find_element_by_id("search-box-input")
zillow_search.send_keys("california")
search_button1=driver.find_elemenet_by_id("search-icon")
search_button1.click()
```

Comment: Try userDataDir option, it will save your session. Or solve the captcha, sometimes you have to solve the captcha.

Comment: @pguardiario Hi I did solve the captcha as specified, its now that it simply enters the query then clicks enter but remains on the same page. Every certain amount of instances of running the program I get a captcha. Manually solving the captcha helps. But I am wondering why it happens only so often